# Why is buffered writing to a fmemopen()'ed FILE faster than unbuffered?

Tags: c, stdio

For sure, buffered I/O to a file on disk is faster than unbuffered. But why is there a benefit even when writing to a memory buffer?

The following benchmark code example was compiled with gcc 5.40 using optimization option -O3, linked against glibc 2.24. (Be aware that the common glibc 2.23 has bugs concerning fmemopen().)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
  size_t bufsz=65536;
  char buf[bufsz];
  FILE *f;
  int r;

  f=fmemopen(buf,bufsz,"w");
  assert(f!=NULL);

  // setbuf(f,NULL);   // UNCOMMENT TO GET THE UNBUFFERED VERSION

  for(int j=0; j<1024; ++j) {
    for(uint32_t i=0; i<bufsz/sizeof(i); ++i) {
      r=fwrite(&i,sizeof(i),1,f);
      assert(r==1);
    }
    rewind(f);
  }

  r=fclose(f);
  assert(r==0);
}
```

Result for the buffered version:

```
$ gcc -O3 -I glibc-2.24/include/ -L glibc-2.24/lib  test-buffered.c 
$ time LD_LIBRARY_PATH=glibc-2.24/lib ./a.out
real    0m1.137s
user    0m1.132s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Result for the unbuffered version

```
$ gcc -O3 -I glibc-2.24/include/ -L glibc-2.24/lib  test-unbuffered.c 
$ time LD_LIBRARY_PATH=glibc-2.24/lib ./a.out
real    0m2.266s
user    0m2.256s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Hint: you should add `-std=C11` `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to compile commands.

Comment: If you try it with different optimization levels, do you get similar results?

Comment: @LPs The OP is using GCC 5 which defaults to `-std=gnu11` so C11 support is there.

Comment: @Joachim: Changing optimization level has almost no difference: Compiling without optimization at all gives 1.216s versa 2.288s user time.

Comment: I think the key is that unbuffered still dealing with physically write the data to stream, while buffered only store values that will be flushed to stream at a later time.

Comment: Use much larger buffers and larger write-block size.

Comment: @Olaf: I do not know, what you mean with larger buffers. But for sure, if I increase the blocks I write in each iteration, then the program gets faster. Still -- both, buffered and unbuffered versions get faster - the difference seems to stay the same. I tried with changing uint32_t to uint64_t, writing 8 bytes at once instead of 4: I get 0.612s versa 0m1.168s user time.

Comment: As an educated guess: writing unbuffered probably causes more system calls.

Comment: @DanielJour On the other hand writing to an in- memory buffer (which is what `fmemopen` creates)  should not cause any systems calls at all, which is corroborated by the zero system time in both cases.

Comment: 8 bytes is far, far from "larger". Benchmarking is a virtue. @DanielJour: Yes, that's what I'm after (actually library overhead). But 8 instead of 4 bytes won't change anything.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't know if that's true. From a short look (I'm on a small mobile phone, so this is probably horribly wrong) it seems to me that at least the current glibc actually does system calls.

Comment: @Olaf: So you are suggesting to do a manual buffering. Then, I would prefer to keep the standard library buffering. Still ... I would have expected, that buffering is not necessary at all.

Comment: @ralfg: Where do I recommend that?? I recommend you first learn about how to benchmark properly. This includes examining how the benchmarked code works **first**.

Comment: I checked the library source code: in fmemopen.c there is a function called fmemopen_write(). I suppose, this is called on fflush() in buffered mode and on each fwrite() in unbuffered mode.

Comment: ... The code contains one central memcpy(), no other syscalls.

Comment: ... However, there is some logic around checking for buffer overflow, and some logic, adding a null byte after the data, iff there is space for the nullbyte. -- Thus I supose, this additional logic causes the overhead.

Comment: Can you compile and link against muscl? I was able to read through its implementation, which does not feature a single system call for fmemopen files.

Comment: @Daniel: What is muscl? Can you give me some link?

Comment: @ralfg that c was too much. I mean https://www.musl-libc.org/

Comment: @Daniel: I installed musl, musl-dev and musl-tools on Ubuntu 16.04 and compiled with musl-gcc. Result: 0m0.848s (buffered) versa 0m0.664s (unbuffered). This is a ratio what I expected in the beginning. Thus: a big hint, that glibc has some (for memfiles unnecessary) syscalls:( And, concerning memfiles, musl outperforms glibc quite significant. Thanks for this hint!

Comment: ... Sorry, I swapped the numbers. It is 0.664s (buffered) versa 0.848s (unbuffered). Still unbuffered is slower than buffered, however, the difference is not as big.

Answer (score 5):

The buffered version performance record:

```
Samples: 19K of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 14986217099
Overhead  Command  Shared Object      Symbol
  48.56%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_fwrite
  27.79%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5
  11.80%  fwrite   fwrite             [.] main
   9.10%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] __GI___mempcpy
   1.56%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] __memcpy_sse2
   0.19%  fwrite   fwrite             [.] fwrite@plt
   0.19%  fwrite   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] native_write_msr_safe
   0.10%  fwrite   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] apic_timer_interrupt
   0.06%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] fmemopen_write
   0.04%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_cookie_write
   0.04%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   0.03%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   0.03%  fwrite   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] rb_next
   0.03%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_default_xsputn
   0.03%  fwrite   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] rcu_check_callbacks
```

the unbuffered version performance record:

```
Samples: 35K of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 26769401637
Overhead  Command  Shared Object      Symbol
  33.36%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5
  25.58%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_fwrite
  12.23%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] fmemopen_write
   6.09%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] __memcpy_sse2
   5.94%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   5.39%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_cookie_write
   5.08%  fwrite   fwrite             [.] main
   4.69%  fwrite   libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   0.59%  fwrite   fwrite             [.] fwrite@plt
   0.33%  fwrite   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] native_write_msr_safe
   0.18%  fwrite   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] apic_timer_interrupt
   0.04%  fwrite   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] timerqueue_add
   0.03%  fwrite   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] rcu_check_callbacks
   0.03%  fwrite   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] ktime_get_update_offsets_now
   0.03%  fwrite   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] trigger_load_balance
```

The diff:

```
# Baseline    Delta  Shared Object      Symbol                            
# ........  .......  .................  ..................................
#
    48.56%  -22.98%  libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_fwrite                    
    27.79%   +5.57%  libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5  
    11.80%   -6.72%  fwrite             [.] main                          
     9.10%           libc-2.17.so       [.] __GI___mempcpy                
     1.56%   +4.54%  libc-2.17.so       [.] __memcpy_sse2                 
     0.19%   +0.40%  fwrite             [.] fwrite@plt                    
     0.19%   +0.14%  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] native_write_msr_safe         
     0.10%   +0.08%  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] apic_timer_interrupt          
     0.06%  +12.16%  libc-2.17.so       [.] fmemopen_write                
     0.04%   +5.35%  libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_cookie_write              
     0.04%   +5.91%  libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
     0.03%   +4.65%  libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5     
     0.03%   -0.01%  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] rb_next                       
     0.03%           libc-2.17.so       [.] _IO_default_xsputn            
     0.03%   +0.00%  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] rcu_check_callbacks           
     0.02%   -0.01%  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] run_timer_softirq             
     0.02%   -0.01%  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] cpuacct_account_field         
     0.02%   -0.00%  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __hrtimer_run_queues          
     0.02%   +0.01%  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] ktime_get_update_offsets_now
```

After digging into the source code, I found the `fwrite`, which is `_IO_fwrite` in iofwrite.c, is just a wrapper function of the actual write function `_IO_sputn`.
And also found:

```
libioP.h:#define _IO_XSPUTN(FP, DATA, N) JUMP2 (__xsputn, FP, DATA, N)
libioP.h:#define _IO_sputn(__fp, __s, __n) _IO_XSPUTN (__fp, __s, __n)
```

As the `__xsputn` function is actual the `_IO_file_xsputn`, which can be found as follows:

```
fileops.c:  JUMP_INIT(xsputn, _IO_file_xsputn),
fileops.c:# define _IO_new_file_xsputn _IO_file_xsputn
fileops.c:versioned_symbol (libc, _IO_new_file_xsputn, _IO_file_xsputn, GLIBC_2_1);
```

At last, down into the `_IO_new_file_xsputn` function in fileops.c, the related part of code is as follows:

```
/* Try to maintain alignment: write a whole number of blocks.  */
      block_size = f->_IO_buf_end - f->_IO_buf_base;
      do_write = to_do - (block_size >= 128 ? to_do % block_size : 0);

      if (do_write)
    {
      count = new_do_write (f, s, do_write);
      to_do -= count;
      if (count < do_write)
        return n - to_do;
    }

      /* Now write out the remainder.  Normally, this will fit in the
     buffer, but it's somewhat messier for line-buffered files,
     so we let _IO_default_xsputn handle the general case. */
      if (to_do)
    to_do -= _IO_default_xsputn (f, s+do_write, to_do);
```

On a RHEL 7.2, the `block_size` equals 8192 if buffer was enabled, otherwise equals 1.

So there are to cases:

- case 1: with the buffer enabled

  do_write = to_do - (to_do % block_size) = to_do - (to_do % 8192)

In our case,
`to_do = sizeof(uint32)`
so the `do_write = 0`, and will call the `_IO_default_xsputn` function.

- case 2: without buffer

`new_do_write` function, after that, `to_do` is zero.
And `new_do_write` is just a wrapper call to `_IO_SYSWRITE`

```
libioP.h:#define _IO_SYSWRITE(FP, DATA, LEN) JUMP2 (__write, FP, DATA, LEN)
```

As we can see, the `_IO_SYSWRITE` is actual the `fmemopen_write` call.
So, the performance difference is caused by the `fmemopen_write` call.
And that was proved by the performance record showed before.

At last, this question is very good, and I'm very interested in it, and it helps me learn some IO function under the surface. See https://oxnz.github.io/2016/08/11/fwrite-perf-issue/ for more information about other platforms.

Comment: Great analysis, so far. Thanks. How do you get the performance records?

Comment: Glad it helps.

For performance records,  you need the `perf` package.
then suppose your code compiles to something named `fwrite`, so you just invoke `perf record ./fwrite`, this would direct the perf to sample the running statistics of the `fwrite` to a file named `perf.data`, after that, call `perf report` to view it.

Comment: @ralfg: You can also use the valgrind suite, which offers callgrind, a performance profiler. Then you can have a visual (and thorough) report through programs like kcachegrind.

Comment: That's true. Which profiler to use is depend on your purpose. The `perf` command use sample to collect data, so it's not that accurate, but more light-weight. So I recommend to use `perf` first, in order to have an overall knowledge about the performance. And then use some more accurate profilers like `callgrind` to address the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for your help so far.

I checked the library source code of glibc 2.24, and it seems that the additional logic for adding a 0-Byte at each flush is responsible for the time-overhead. See also the man-page:

> When a stream that has been opened for writing is flushed (fflush(3))
>   or closed (fclose(3)), a null byte is written at the end of the
>   buffer if there is space.

In unbuffered mode, this Null-Byte is added after each fwrite(), just to be  overwritten with the next fwrite().

I copy the library source code for fmemopen_write(), for those who also were wondering about this strange behavour...

```
static ssize_t
fmemopen_write (void *cookie, const char *b, size_t s)
{
  fmemopen_cookie_t *c = (fmemopen_cookie_t *) cookie;;
  _IO_off64_t pos = c->append ? c->maxpos : c->pos;
  int addnullc = (s == 0 || b[s - 1] != '\0');

  if (pos + s > c->size)
    {
      if ((size_t) (c->pos + addnullc) >= c->size)
    {
      __set_errno (ENOSPC);
      return 0;
    }
      s = c->size - pos;
    }

  memcpy (&(c->buffer[pos]), b, s);

  c->pos = pos + s;
  if ((size_t) c->pos > c->maxpos)
    {
      c->maxpos = c->pos;
      if (c->maxpos < c->size && addnullc)
    c->buffer[c->maxpos] = '\0';
      /* A null byte is written in a stream open for update iff it fits. */
      else if (c->append == 0 && addnullc != 0)
    c->buffer[c->size-1] = '\0';
    }

  return s;
}
```

Comment: Well, still thinking. What I described, only affects the first loop of j in my benchmark program. After this, I rewind, but the file keeps its size (i.e. maxpos marking EOF keeps a big number in source code). Thus the Adding of Null bytes do not occur in the loops j=1 to 1024. Any other idea?

Comment: I doubt that. The function you show is most certainly not called directly but rather via a syscall, which then returns control back to said function.

Answer (score 0):

When calling into a library, then the optimization level of the code, is not affected by the code, and would be constant.

That is why changing the write size doesn't affect the ratio within your test limits.  (If the write size tended towards your data size, then your code would dominate).

The cost to call fwrite will cause a decision of whether to flush the data or not.

Although I am not sure of the implementation of fwrite for memory streams, if the call gets close to the kernel, then there is a likelihood that the `syscall` or security gate on the OS function results in dominating the cost.  This cost is why writing data is best matching the underlying store.

Empirically I have found file systems work reasonably well with 8kb chunks.  I would consider 4kb for a memory system - as this is the size of a processor page boundary.